# Play Framework scala project

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies, sbt

I am currently trying to set up a new play project from scratch and have installed play to my windows laptop however when building the project I get this error:

`Sbt.librarymanagment.ResolveException: Error downloading play:sbt-plugin;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12.2.0`

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your build. 2.12.2.0 is not a Scala version in any way.

Comment: @cchantep
This is what is in my build, no mention of scalaversion:

`import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "LMDashboard"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      // Add your own project settings here      
    )

}`